# Why are async methods, which return an IAsyncEnumerable, implemented as classes instead of structs?

Tags: c#, state-machine, c#-9.0, iasyncenumerable

I am curious to why async methods returning an `IAsyncEnumerable` compile down to a state machine, which is defined as a class instead of a struct as it usually is. See the following example:

```cs
public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> MethodOne() 
{ 
    await Task.Delay(10);
    yield return 0;
}

// Compiled version

[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <MethodOne>d__0 : IAsyncEnumerable<int>, IAsyncEnumerator<int>,
    IAsyncDisposable, IValueTaskSource<bool>, IValueTaskSource, IAsyncStateMachine
{
    // Omitted for brevity 
}
```

[Sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEBMBGAsAKBQBgAIUMBWAblwOIwDoAVACwTggBMBLAOwHNK8iJACz9CYwlQDMxNIQDCEnAG9c44tJQAOQgEkAglACeXAMYBRLgFcwiCMAA2cADzcYAPkIBZODEYB7NgB5LjgACgBKRTUlKLVxFABOYgA2WgAROHsIQ1CMfHDROLFVIpoMYgB2QnxCsQBfXDqgA)

```cs
public async Task<int> MethodTwo() 
{ 
    await Task.Delay(10);
        
    return 0;
}

// Compiled version

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
[CompilerGenerated]
private struct <MethodTwo>d__0 : IAsyncStateMachine
{
    // Omitted for brevity 
}
```

[Sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEBMBGAsAKBQBgAIUMBWAblwOIwDoAVACwTggBMBLAOwHNK8iJACz9CYwlQDMxNIQDCEnAG9c44tJQAOYgDYAPNxgA+QgFk4MRgHs29AO5WAFAEpFapW7XiUATl20AETgAGwgAT0cMfGdRLzFVOOIAdkJ8WLEAX1wMoA==)

Comment: Who knows what microsoft did in their last frameworks, but they wanted to exclude heap allocations for async operations. maybe it is the reason.

Comment: Probably because the async statemachine not always continues on the same thread? So bennefits of a struct over a class, are not used here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The state machine *itself* implements `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, and is `new`ed up and returned as the `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` instance. If it was a struct type, it would be immediately boxed by the conversion to an interface type anyway.

Comment: One could say the same thing for `IAsyncStateMachine` for the async method example. I don't see how this guess (and let's be clear: you _are_ just guessing here, when it comes to answering "why did Microsoft do it this way?") actually explains the difference.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: The state machine for `async Task` methods is only boxed when necessary; for methods that can complete synchronously, it is never boxed and a completed `Task` instance is returned. Since the state machine for `async IAsyncEnumerable<T>` methods *is* the returned instance, it would *always* have to be boxed. And I guess quite often. ;)

Comment: That's a reasonable point to support your speculation, but it belongs in the answer, not the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare it with the state machine generated for an `IEnumerable<T>`, which is also a class:

```
public IEnumerable<int> MethodThree() 
{ 
    yield return 0;
}

// Compiled version

[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <MethodThree>d__0 : IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable,
    IEnumerator<int>, IDisposable, IEnumerator
{
    // Omitted for brevity 
}

[IteratorStateMachine(typeof(<MethodThree>d__0))]
public IEnumerable<int> MethodThree()
{
    return new <MethodThree>d__0(-2);
}
```

[Sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEBMBGAsAKBQBgAIUMBWAblwOIwDoAVACwTggBMBLAOwHNK8iJACz9CYwlQDMxNIQDCEnAG9c44tJKSAPNxgA+QgFk4MRgHs2TFnAAUASkVqljteJIZiAdkL5R4gL64/kA)

Comment: Based on the other answer, since `IEnumerable` / `IAsynEnumberable` doesn't start until `MoveNext` is called, a struct would always need to be boxed anyway. If a `Task` completes synchronously, the box allocation can sometimes be avoided.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman yeap, indeed. Btw the first step at starting an (async) enumerable is to call its `Get(Async)Enumerator` method, which instantiates a state machine. The `MoveNext(Async)` comes next, and sets the state machine in motion. After realizing that, the second part of my answer seems now wrong.